# How to use deleteById jpa repository if my id is a String?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I need to delete an entity using its ID, tried using JPA repository delete by id method

```
 productRepository.deleteById(id);
```

Where "id" is supposed to be Long- If passed string value will give an error: Long expected

```
Sample id= "402880f17ebd7e44017ebd7fe9ee0000"
```

Hence I can't convert the String to Long

Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {

@Id @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid",strategy = "uuid")
@Column(name="product_id")
private String id;

@Column(name="price")
@NotNull
private float productPrice;

@Column(name="product_name")
@NotNull
private String productName;

@Column(name="description")
private String productDesc;

@Column(name="stock_available")
private int productStock;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "shop_id")
private Shop shop;

public Product(){
}

public Product(String id, float productPrice, String productName, String productDesc, int productStock, Shop shop) {
    this.id = id;
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productDesc = productDesc;
    this.productStock = productStock;
    this.shop = shop;
}
}
```

Repository Class:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long>{
}
```

Comment: add to a question details about your entity and repo

Comment: Well? How _are_ you supposed to convert that string to an integral value? Is that a hex string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your productRepository change the second generic type on the interface from long to string. So Change your code snippet

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long> {}
```

to:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,String> {}
```

Also, you don't need `@Repository` for Spring data JPA interfaces.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that ?

Comment: @ShashankPrasad What Daniel probably means, is that you are extending from `JpaRepository<Product, Long>`, where `Product` is your entity class and `Long` is the type of the id. Since you are using a `String` as id instead of a `Long`, you should extend from `JpaRepository<Product, String>`.

Comment: I have updated my answer for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,String> {}
```

> Simply write above line using String and without @Repository

> Explanation:

- 2nd argument of JpaRepository is type of Id of that dto
- Any commponent related annotations are useless on interfaces, it will require only on classes so @Repository should apply only if you write implementation class of ProductRepository interface

Answer (score 0):

In your ProductRepository, when you are extending the `JpaRepository<EntityName,EntityId Type>.`
In your case, you are using the field id as string but extending the type as Long.
To solve your problem, either take the input in the form of Long number or convert the primary key type to String.

Answer (score 0):

The primary key type is wrong, should be ‘String’, not ‘Long’:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,String>{
}
```